# How can I use an IIFE in the return function of a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal page popping up when the user clicks a button, it's working perfectly :

```
render() {
  return (
     <div>
         <section>
             <button onClick={() => this.refs.simpleDialog.show()}>Open Modal</button>
         </section>
         <SkyLight hideOnOverlayClicked ref="simpleDialog" title="Test Modal">
             Text that appears inside the modal page
            <Button onClick={() => this.refs.simpleDialog.hide()} >Got It</Button>
         </SkyLight>
    </div>
)}
```

- But My goal is to open the modal automatically when the user opens the page for the first time.
- I don't want to open the modal page by clicking on a button

**Question**:

- Can I use an IIFE (An immediately-invoked function expression) in order to open the modal as soon as the user open the page ?
- My approach was to set a boolean to true. Then open the modal if the value is set to true

Library being used for the modal :
https://github.com/marcio/react-skylight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [componentDidMount()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.simpleDialog.show();
}
```

From the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

Feel free to checkout other [component lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

Comment: Great this helped a lot

Comment: I have another question: how can I call `this.refs.simpleDialog.show()` from another component. I have a component for the header of my page that contains a button. I want to click on that button in order to display a modal page (that is another component) ?

Comment: @AziCode - real similar to how you're calling the SkyLight component. You can wrap that `show()` call in a public method on your child component's class and then from the parent component, use the refs collection and call that method.

Comment: I created a question, can you please have a look and expand on what you said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474580/how-to-call-a-component-method-from-another-component

Comment: I've added an answer, expanding on my comment.

Answer (score 1):

To have a model open on component mount, just set isVisible to true

```
<SkyLight isVisible={true} ref="simpleDialog" title="Test Modal">
```

Comment: Good find. However, looking at the source code, it seems only the stateless version supports that?