# React expose component function and getting data with ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is regarding a question that I have just asked here : [React expose component function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474784/react-expose-component-function)

So when using componentDidMount on the 2 components where the functions are exposed, it looks like the componentDidMount for the data function takes some time to load, and then this causes returning an empty array. I am pretty new to react so I am not sure if this is the right way to use them.

```
class Data extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            names: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        $.get('data.json', function (result) {
            this.setState({
                names: result.names
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }

    getNames(){
        return this.state.names;
    }

    render(){
        return (<div></div>);
    }

}


class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            test: []
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.test = this.refs.hello.getNames();
        console.log(this.refs.hello.getNames());
    }

    something(){
        console.log(this.state.test);
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Data ref='hello' />
                {this.something()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />,  app);
```

Comment: Is this a contrived example or actual code?  Reason I ask is to determine whether you need the `Data` component?  It seems the data could be retrieved in `Layout` instead.

Comment: owww... do you think is good practice in react?

Comment: I'm with sma, this code does not make sense since there is no reason for the child component to fetch the data.  React Components are meant to be views.  Having one named `Data` that does nothing visual is likely going off the intended path.

Comment: Ok!... I think this is my beginner thinking. I will remove Data.. and change the initial idea I had... thanks!

Comment: Once you get the Data component out of the way, you may have an easier time.  If you still get stuck, though, post here (or post another question and update this one)

Comment: it is working thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have done a mistake of assigning value to a state in the layout component like `this.state.test = this.refs.hello.getNames();`, where you should be using setState(); Also it better to retrieve the data in the `Layout` component and if you want to use the data in `Data` component too then you can pass it as a prop to the same like

```
class Data extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render(){
        console.log(this.props.names)
        return (<div></div>);
    }

}


class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            test: []
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.get('data.json', function (result) {
            this.setState({
                test: result.names
            });
        }.bind(this));

    }

    something(){
        console.log(this.state.test);
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Data ref='hello' names={this.state.test}/>
                {this.something()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />,  app);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are fetching in `componentDidMount`, you should be fetching in `componentWillMount`, that way you have the data before the component is rendered

Per the docs:

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before `render()`, (therefore setting `state` in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.)

All you need to do is change `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount`

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: If the change is made to use componentWillMount then state.test will not be set since the ref will be empty.  IMO, if the parent needs to be made aware of some data in a child component, the parent should pass in a callback as a prop to the child.  This also keeps the components more reusable.

Comment: callback sounds a good idea, I am only not sure how to do this in react...